# How to detect loading of imge is completed in Awesomium.net?

Tags: c#, awesomium

I use Awesomium 1.6 in my C#-WPF application for display images from certain url. I Want after loading and displaying of image completed, close the WebControl. How Can I Do This?

Answer (score 0):

You can determine when the page load is complete by registering to the [WebControl.LoadCompleted](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_6/sharp_api/html/6becad6a-eafc-79c9-b02a-c71d1b362e10.htm) event. That event is triggered when the page has finished loading and rendering.

You can tell your WebControl to close by using the [WebControl.Close()](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_6/sharp_api/html/fc8e4f91-15a7-0f4a-fc40-a3b2ca62fdeb.htm) method. This kills your WebControl.